# Drop column using Dask dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

This should work:

`raw_data.drop('some_great_column', axis=1).compute(`)

But the column is not dropped. In pandas I use:

```
raw_data.drop(['some_great_column'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But inplace does not exist in Dask. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can separate into two operations:

```
# dask operation
raw_data = raw_data.drop('some_great_column', axis=1)

# conversion to pandas
df = raw_data.compute()
```

Then export the Pandas dataframe to a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv(r'out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I guess the transformation to pandas will potentially fail due to memory issues ... the reason why I started to use Dask ...

Comment: I see, but that's going to happen *anyway* when you use `compute`, even in your original code. You can try filtering and exporting in groups if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to keep "raw data" in a Dask DF. In that case the following will do the trick:

```
new_raw_df = raw_data.drop('some_great_column', axis=1).copy()
```

where `type(new_raw_df)` is `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame` and you can delete the original DF.